# How do I access a new environment?

Tags: r

I have a script and I want to run some tests on the script. If I stay in my current environment, `R_GlobalEnv`, then I need to rename all of the variables for my testing since I'll run commands that overwrite them.

I'd like to create a new environment and recreate my objects and then be able to manipulate them freely without worrying how that effects my original workspace.

I don't want to create a new RStudio instance or workspace. I want to run these tests from a new RScript document in the same RStudio instance.

I know that I can create a new environment with `new.env(parent = emptyenv())`

How do I switch between the global environment and my new environment and then back?

Comment: What you're describing is `attach` and `detach`, but they're out of fashion. `eval` is an alternative that lets you execute arbitrary code in an environment.

Comment: I think this is too broad unless you can give a clear example of what you'll have in your environment and the kinds of tests you want to run. I think it also shows the benefits of turning each small chunk of your analysis into a function, because then you can test the function without worrying too much about the global state.

Comment: @Marius, I'll take your recommendation about making my code more modular. I think that's a natural part of the process for becoming a more advanced programmer. In terms of the types of objects, it's importing data and then transforming that data in various ways. I know that's fairly unspecific.

Comment: @alistaire, a generalized eval is exactly what I'm talking about. It seems like `attach` is to `with` in the same way what I want is to `eval`.

Comment: Generalized how? `with` is pretty much the same as `evalq`, the quoting version. You can pass these functions multiline expressions wrapped in `{...}`. rlang has some nice environment tools, too, e.g. `env_clone`, which would let you copy your global environment so you can run code against the copy (via `with` or `evalq` or whatever), and keep the original untouched. Or use functions as Marius suggested, which is an easy way to layer on top of the global environment. Their environments disappear after they're run, though, so you do have to return whatever you want to keep.

Comment: Generalized in the sense that I do not need to wrap each of the functions in `eval` or `evalq`. Is it possible to create a new environment, load it as the active environment that processes functions and then switch back to the global environment or a previous environment?